# Custom fields can't be displayed in Gantt view's left pane (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I created a custom field type that inherits from SPFieldNumber. Then I created a column of this type in a list and created a Gantt View.

The problem is that the column doesn't show in the Gantt view's left pane.

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this elsewhere in the end?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010 fields UI is rendered using XSL Transformation, so to get you field rendered in List View you need to write a Custom XSL for your Field you developed.

Below article will get you needed help

1. [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606773.aspx)
2. [Reference Article](http://www.silver-it.com/node/66)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that rendering Gantt view is not related to XSL Transformation. Thanks, anyway.